# In K8S, how to use data from existed secret when creating new secret?

Tags: templates, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We got an existed secret in K8S(suppose it is "secret_1") and we want to write a yaml to create a new secret "secret_2", using some values from secret_1.

That is, in this yaml we'd like to

1. Read values from other secret
2. Store values to new secret

Is it possible to do this? It will be great help if a sample can be provided.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this directly in YAML. You would need to write a script of some kind to do the steps you described, though you can use `kubectl get secret -o yaml` (or `-o json`) for a lot of the heavy lifting, possibly with `jq` for the reformatting.

Comment: Thanks. I did something like "   kubectl get secret <old-secret> -o json | jq '.data["<new-key>"]="<new_value>"' | kubectl apply -f -    "

Comment:  Sounds about like I expect :) You can also use Kustomize for some stuff like this, but I don't think you can use existing objects as a source so this is probably better anyway.